# MMA not showing bounding box for 3D plots

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I'm not sure if this is a problem with MMA or my sytem but I'm facing a strange issue with 3D plots.

MMA is not showing the bounding box it just displays the plot. Do any of you know the possible reason. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.
I tried restarting and even upgraded from MMA 11.2 to 11.3 but still the anomaly persists.

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, Boxed -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a possible bug. Have you considered asking WRI support?

Comment: What happens if you add `BoxStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0, 1]`?

Comment: `BoxStyle` has no effect. Still getting the same output. And If it is bug then shouldn't if effect everyone.

Comment: I wanted to chip in - MMA 11.3 on Win7, no problem encountered.

Comment: Similarly, on MMA 11.2 on Win7-64: the box and axes are displayed fine.

Comment: What if you switch the global option value of `3DRenderingEngine` to something like `Mesa`

Comment: @user6014 Yes ! It worked. Thanks. Can you please write it as an answer. Maybe you can show the path to `3DRenderingEngine` in preferences.

Comment: Works fine on macOS 10.13.4 running V11.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is likely some poor interaction with Mathematica and your graphics driver. Because of this I would first recommend ensuring your graphics are fully up to date with what your GPU manufacturer has on their website.

If that doesn't resolve the issue and something is still going wrong, I would change the global `3DRenderingEngine` in Mathematica's [Option Inspector](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionInspector.html) to something like Mesa. This uses a different engine to render the graphics, one which may not demonstrate the issue.

Note that other engines may be slower (esp. Mesa, since I believe it is a software based engine) or have issues of their own, so while this may fix this issue it may introduce others.